# Validating form using HTML and JavaScript - Checking form input matches a value in an array

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple web form which accepts a user email and password for log in. 
I want to check the users email and password match up with what is stored in an external javascript file and if the combination matches then proceed to the index.html page.

My array is declared in my router file as follows:

```
var USERS = { users: [] };

function User(type, useremail, password) {
 this.type = type;
 this.useremail = useremail;
 this.password = password;
}

var Bob = new User("rep", "bob@bob.com", "qwerty");
USERS.users.push(Bob);

var Helen = new User("rep", "helen@helen.com", "test");
USERS.users.push(Helen);

var Dominic = new User("customer", "dom@dom.com", "1234");
USERS.users.push(Dominic);

var James = new User("grower", "james@james.com", "pass1");
USERS.users.push(James);
```

My html form is as follows:

```
 <div id="loginform"> 
    <form id ="login" name="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="return verify();"> 
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <label>
        <span>Email Address:</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address" required />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
        <span>Password:</span>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
        </label>
        <br> <br>
        <label id="reset"><a href="#">Click here to reset your password</a>               
        </label>
        <br>
        <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </label>       

<!-- <input type="submit" value="Login" onsubmit = "verify()"> --><!--  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> -->

      </form> <!-- End of log in form -->
   </div>
```

My attempt at checking if the user email and password combo match:

```
function verify() {

validUser = false;

    for (var x in USERS.users){
        //console.log(USERS.users[x].userid);
        if (query.useremail === USERS.users[x].useremail
           && query.password === USERS.users[x].password)              
        {
                validUser = true;
                break;
         } // end of if

    }// end of for

  console.log(validUser);

    if (validUser === true){
    console.log("logged in");
    res.render('index.html');
    }
}
```

Just in case you need to see it, a section in my router where I feedback the log in page on request:

```
    app.get('/views/login.html', function (req, res) {
        res.render('../views/login.html');
        //console.log("Log in page displayed");

    });


    app.post('/views/login.html', function (req, res) {
        var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
        var query = url_parts.query;

    console.log(query);
    console.log("Username: " + query.useremail);
    console.log("Password: " + query.password);

});
```

I've confused myself with all the different codes and files ... How do I go about verifying that the user can log in?

Where do I put my verify() function? I currently have it within the router file below the user data - but I want to use it within HTML so I was considering putting into  tags there...?

Comment: This is authentication right? So it must be on the backend use server side langs like php, asp,rails...

Answer (score 0):

I supose that you use Javascript as server with NodeJS, then you need to create a route for `<form id ="login" action="path"...` wiht method `POST`. In the server:

```
app.post([path type on action], function(req, res) {
 verify();
}
```

You catch input values: `req.body.[attr name of input]`. For example, for email:

```
var email = req.body.email;
```

Comment: Could You show me a structure of your proyect?  Look this proyect https://github.com/Erik91Lucio/blog_2012 The routes are in app.js

Comment: In line 102 is the route for login: app.get('/login',  sessionController.new);

Comment: Main folder nodejs --> Contains: node_modules, public (contains css (contains style.css)), router (contains main.js), views (contains index.html and views.html), expressserver.js, package.json

Comment: In the route don´t put the .htlml files. Only the path like this: app.post('/login', sessionController.create); And in controller you render the view. Do You understand the code of my blog?

Comment: not really... sorry. I'm quite new to all of this. Have only be working with it for a couple of weeks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71769/discussion-between-erik-lucio-and-hturner).